Dropdown menu behaves wrong when <button> is changed to <a>
I have a dropdown menu that works as expected when using a <button> element. The menu appears right below the button as it should be. However, when I change the element to an <a> tag, the dropdown menu appears on top of the <a>, not below it.
Why is the behavior different between the <button> and <a> elements? How can I make the dropdown menu appear below the  tag just like it does with the <button>?
Any help would be appreciated!
HTML (with a href it's not working)
<div class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropbtn">Dropdown 1</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">Link 1</a>
          <a href="#">Link 2</a>
          <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
    </div>

HTML (with button it's working)
<div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown 2</button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">Link 1</a>
          <a href="#">Link 2</a>
          <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
    </div>

CSS
.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
 }

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  display: block;
  background-color: #1f7ac4;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  border: 1px solid #1f7ac4;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 19px;
  line-height: 36px; /* Must be the same as font-size .topnav a.logo */
}
.dropdown .dropbtn:hover{
    background-color: #2f8fde;
    border-top-left-radius: 12px;
    border-top-right-radius: 12px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 12px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 12px;
    border: 1px solid #2f8fde;
    color: #f2f2f2;
}
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-top-left-radius: 12px;
    border-top-right-radius: 12px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 12px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 12px;
    border: 1px solid #d6d2d2;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    min-width: 160px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 10px 10px 5px 10px;
    z-index: 1;
}
.dropdown-content a {
    float: none;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-top-left-radius: 12px;
    border-top-right-radius: 12px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 12px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 12px;
    border: 0px;
    color: #3c4043;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 32px;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0px 0px 5px 0px;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  color: #3c4043;
  border: 0px;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

I found the following solution
I changed margin: 66px 0px 0px 0px; at .dropdown-content.
Is this a good solution? With the <button> I didn't need a fixed margin.

Please show us an example - see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Can you make the code into a runnable snippet (use <> in the editor) and check that it definitely shows the problem, because I cannot reproduce it - I just see the second example having the drop down without such a big margin/padding above it. I don't see any overwriting.

I added a snippet. Just see the links "Dropdown 1" and "Dropdown 2". "Dropdown 2" is just working fine.

I changed margin: 66px 0px 0px 0px; at .dropdown-content. Is this a good solution? With the "button" I didn't need a fixed margin.

See answer just put up. Whether your solution is 'good' would be to give an 'opinion' which is frowned on on SO. I would prefer not to have special settings, especially of fixed px values, where possible in order to maintain responsiveness.

You may like to look into more 'modern' methods of arranging a line of elements - CSS flex or grid rather than float.

A problem is that you are setting all a element descendants of .topnav with .topnav a which I think should be .topnav > a i.e. target only the direct children.


#header {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #1f7ac4;
  padding: 25px 0px 25px 0px;
}

.topnav>a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  border: 1px solid #1f7ac4;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  margin: 0px 5px 0px 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 19px;
  line-height: 36px;
  /* Must be the same as font-size .topnav a.logo */
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #2f8fde;
  border-top-left-radius: 12px;
  border-top-right-radius: 12px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 12px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #1f7ac4;
  color: #f2f2f2;
}

.topnav a.active {
  border-top-left-radius: 12px;
  border-top-right-radius: 12px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 12px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
  color: #f2f2f2;
}

.topnav a.logo {
  font-size: 36px;
  /* Must be the same as line-height .topnav a */
  margin-left: -16px;
}

.topnav a.logo:hover {
  background-color: #1f7ac4;
}

.topnav {
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0px auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  display: block;
  background-color: #1f7ac4;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  border: 1px solid #1f7ac4;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 19px;
  line-height: 36px;
  /* Must be the same as font-size .topnav a.logo */
}

.dropdown .dropbtn:hover {
  background-color: #2f8fde;
  border-top-left-radius: 12px;
  border-top-right-radius: 12px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 12px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #2f8fde;
  color: #f2f2f2;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-top-left-radius: 12px;
  border-top-right-radius: 12px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 12px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #d6d2d2;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  min-width: 160px;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  padding: 10px 10px 5px 10px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-top-left-radius: 12px;
  border-top-right-radius: 12px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 12px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 12px;
  border: 0px;
  color: #3c4043;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 32px;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0px 0px 5px 0px;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  color: #3c4043;
  border: 0px;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
<div id="header">
  <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
    <a href="https://example.com/" class="logo">Example</a>
    <a href="#">Example</a>
    <a href="#">Example</a>
    <a href="#">Example</a>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropbtn">Dropdown 1</a>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Link 1:</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown 2</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
      <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>




Thanks. .topnav>a is all I needed.

Make sure to adjust the CSS to make sure the dropdown starts below the anchor tag just like it does for the button.


.dropdown-toggle {
  display: inline-block; /* Ensure it's block-level for consistent positioning */
  position: relative; /* Enable positioning relative to the <a> element */
}

.dropdown-menu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%; 
  left: 0;
}

.dropdown-toggle:hover .dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">Dropdown</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li><a href="#">Option 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Option 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Option 3</a></li>
</ul>



